# Gamma Correction for qt5 console application

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

The below code is the example from Qt documentation, which explains basically about adjusting the property gamma to a specific `Item`.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Item {
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Image {
        id: bug
        source: "images/bug.jpg"
        sourceSize: Qt.size(parent.width, parent.height)
        smooth: true
        visible: false
    }

    GammaAdjust {
        anchors.fill: bug
        source: bug
        gamma: 0.45
    }
}
```

Is there a way to set the gamma correction as a whole to the complete application so that the color depth can be corrected the way I wanted it to be, instead of defaults.

Something similar to this:

> xrandr --output DVI-0 --gamma 2:2:1

Comment: "Console applicaton" by definition does not have a GUI and does not really care about gamma (except if it is a tool for adjusting OS gamma stuff, like `xrandr`). What I mean is, you might want to edit the question title, it is now rather confusing. Do you mean "How to write a console application to adust gamma of a GUI application?"

Comment: @hyde Yeah, what I mean was am developing a GUI application that contains multiple qml files and each file does a specific job. If I want to adjust gamma for a complete GUI application is there a way *I can set some flags or stuff like that while launching the GUI application*. Currently I need to add `GammaAdjust` in every qml file where I want to have that effect applied.

Comment: @hyde Gamma correction is color-related, console applications are not excluded from outputting color, even graphics, with some cheating, say, by modifying character glyphs.

Comment: @user12345 So you are actually asking this: "How do can I read a command line parameter and use it as gamma correction value in QML code?"

Comment: @user1095108 But console applications are excluded from having the QML *GUI* shown in the question (because if they do have that, then they are not console applications).

Comment: @hyde That's debatable, as you probably know, there are graphics libraries like libcaca and aalib, using which you can display graphics in text mode. There's software-emulated opengl mesa3d. I'm sure you could hook up something to show this GUI in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Use property binding. Create Settings.qml

```
Item
{
    property double gammaValue: 0.45
}
```

And then

```
Item {
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Image {
        id: bug
        source: "images/bug.jpg"
        sourceSize: Qt.size(parent.width, parent.height)
        smooth: true
        visible: false
    }

    GammaAdjust {
        anchors.fill: bug
        source: bug
        gamma: appSettings.gammaValue
    }

    Settings {
        id: appSettings
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you are asking, then you want to access command line arguments. In QML, you can access them by `Qt.application.arguments`. Here's a crude solution, modifed into your question code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Item {
    width: 300
    height: 300

    // gammaIndex will be 0 if --gamma not given, otherwise index of value    
    property int gammaIndex: Qt.application.arguments.indexOf("--gamma") + 1;

    // fallback default value as its own property for clarity
    property real defaultGamma: 1.0

    // rely on short-circuiting logic, result is either //valid or //default
    // an invalid number will give value 0, so --gamma 0 is rejected too
    property real gamma: gammaIndex > 0
                         && Qt.application.arguments[gammaIndex] > 0
                         && Qt.application.arguments[gammaIndex] //valid
                         || defaultGamma //default

    Image {
        id: bug
        source: "images/bug.jpg"
        sourceSize: Qt.size(parent.width, parent.height)
        smooth: true
        visible: false
    }

    GammaAdjust {
        anchors.fill: bug
        source: bug
        gamma: parent.gamma
    }
}
```